# JavaScript find first number in array that is <= to given number

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an array of prime numbers:

```
const primes = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]
```

I want to find the first number in this list that is <= the number given.

For example ... `getHighestPrimeNumber(58)` ... should return 53, being the prime number with the greatest value which is also less than or equal to 58

Expect results:

> getHighestPrimeNumber(58) === 53
>
> getHighestPrimeNumber(53) === 53
>
> getHighestPrimeNumber(52) === 47

My current approach is to iterate through the prime numbers but this is very inefficient, especially given that there may be 10,000+ numbers in the list - thanks

Vanilla JS or Lodash is fine

Comment: Is your list always sorted? Binary search is the way to go.

Comment: yes it is sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you posted this with `lodash` tag just FYI that this with it is **trivial** due to [**_.sortedIndex**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sortedIndex):

```js
const primes = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]

const closestPrime = (n) => {
  let index = _.sortedIndex(primes, n)
  return primes[index] == n ? primes[index] : primes[index-1]
}

console.log(closestPrime(58))
console.log(closestPrime(53))
console.log(closestPrime(52))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good task for a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm):

```js
const bisect = (needle, haystack) => {
  let lo = 0;
  let hi = haystack.length;
  
  while (lo <= hi) {
    const mid = ~~((hi - lo) / 2 + lo);
    
    if (haystack[mid] === needle) {
      return needle;
    }
    else if (haystack[mid] > needle) {
      hi = mid - 1;
    }
    else {
      lo = mid + 1;      
    }
  }
  
  return haystack[hi];
};

const getHighestPrimeNumber = n => {
  const primes = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97];
  return bisect(n, primes);
};

console.log(getHighestPrimeNumber(58) === 53);
console.log(getHighestPrimeNumber(53) === 53);
console.log(getHighestPrimeNumber(52) === 47);
```

A couple of notes:

- You'll likely want to make your prime number array a parameter to `getHighestPrimeNumber` so it isn't created and garbage collected on every function call. At this point, you might as well just call the binary search directly.
- If you're concerned about queries over and under the bounds of the array, you can handle those according to some policy, for example: `return haystack[Math.min(hi,haystack.length-1)];`.
- Binary search is O(n log(n)) time complexity. Set lookups are O(1), so you may experience a performance boost if you maintain a set in addition to the array and try lookups there first.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a field for a divide and conquer approach. Something like a [Binary search](https://www.google.com/search?q=binary%20search&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab):

```
const primes = [3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97]

function findHighestPrimeNumberRecursive(arr, ceiling) {
  const midpoint = arr.length/2
  if(arr[midpoint ] === ceiling){
    // we found it!
    return primes[arr.length-1];
  } else {
    if(arr[midpoint] <== ceiling) {
      return findHighestPrimeNumberRecursive(arr.slice(0, midpoint), ceiling);
    } else {
      return findHighestPrimeNumberRecursive(arr.slice(midpoint, arr.length), ceiling);
    }
  }
}

function getHighestPrimeNumber(ceiling) {
  return findHighestPrimeNumberRecursive(primes, ceiling);
}
```

Comment: Good answer and welcome to SO! I wonder if list slicing and recursive overhead might impact performance on large input arrays, however--it seems the extra verbosity in the index approach might be worth the trouble.